# gradle - unexplainable dependency version coming

Tags: java, spring-boot, selenium-webdriver, gradle

I have a Spring Boot 2.6.1 application for which I use Selenium during my tests.

I am using `selenium-java` `4.6.0`

```
testImplementation group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-java', version: '4.6.0'
```

but the transitive dependencies that are pulled are all older versions (mostly 3.141.59), which leads to some issue at runtime, with classes not found etc :

[image]

I can override all these dependencies manually, but that doesn't look like the right way..

anyway, where are these versions coming from ? I am not defining them anywhere, so I would expect all the versions showed in https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java/4.6.0 to be pulled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I again got tricked by Spring Boot dependency management, which is most of the time super useful, but sometimes confusing like here...

As documented in Spring boot 2.6 , Selenium is managed by the BOM (I was not aware of this), and what a surprise : `v3.141.59` is defined there - so this is where it's coming from, without me defining it anywhere.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.6.6/reference/html/dependency-versions.html#appendix.dependency-versions.properties

[image]

So the solution is quite simple : we simply need to override the version in the gradle build file

```
ext['selenium.version'] = '4.6.0'

dependencies {

    testImplementation group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-java' 
    ...
}
```

and all the "right" dependencies versions are now coming.